# How do I git push to heroku the node app generated by Webstorm ide when selecting a new node application type?

Tags: node.js, heroku, webstorm

I have had no problems deploying the getting started node app at heroku.
My next goal was to deploy the default node app generated by Webstorm 8.0 ide when selecting a node project. I followed the video Getting started with Express found here:
http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/05/guide-to-node-js-development-with-webstorm/

I Tested the app locally & got it to run.

Deployed by starting terminal and logging in to my heroku account.

> MacBook:helgoWS $ heroku apps:create helgows Creating helgows... done,
>   stack is cedar http://helgows.herokuapp.com/ |
>   git@heroku.com:helgows.git Git remote heroku added
>   -----> Launching... done, v3
>          http://helgows.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
>
> To git@heroku.com:helgows.git  * [new branch]      master -> master

I start the "dynos" with

> MacBook:helgoWS $ heroku ps:scale web=1 Scaling dynos... done, now
>   running web at 1:1X. MacBook:helgoWS $ heroku ps
>   === web (1X): `node app.js` web.1: crashed 2014/08/04 23:30:27 (~ 1m ago)

---

Result of logs:

> MacBook:helgoWS $ heroku logs -n 1500
>       2014-08-04T21:24:52.703512+00:00 heroku[api]: Enable Logplex by      helgo@gmail.com
>       2014-08-04T21:24:52.703512+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v2 created by helgo@gmail.com
>       2014-08-04T21:30:13+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
>       2014-08-04T21:30:19.399123+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by helgo@gmail.com
>       2014-08-04T21:30:19+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
>       2014-08-04T21:30:19.514017+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v3 created by helgo@gmail.com
>       2014-08-04T21:30:19.513814+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 54c922f by helgo @gmail.com
>       2014-08-04T21:30:24.697475+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
>       2014-08-04T21:30:24.698086+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
>       2014-08-04T21:30:21.943047+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process  `node app.js`
>       2014-08-04T21:30:24.487283+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
>       2014-08-04T21:30:28.590771+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
>       2014-08-04T21:30:26.191041+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process `node app.js`
>       2014-08-04T21:30:29.589262+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 
>       desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=helgows.herokuapp.com 
>       request_id=ae1baa69-4d1a-475a-8338-4619169e679f fwd="54.196.27.9" 
>       dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
>       2014-08-04T21:30:28.605566+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
>       2014-08-04T21:31:41.003199+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by helgo@gmail.com
>       2014-08-04T21:37:44.191949+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by helgo@gmail.com

here is the app.js file contents:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('static-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(favicon());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

/// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

/// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});


module.exports = app;
```

Note: I am running the free version which i believed allows up to 5 apps

Comment: did you add your dependencies to package.json?

Comment: {
  "name": "helgoWS",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.2.0",
    "static-favicon": "~1.0.0",
    "morgan": "~1.0.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.0.1",
    "body-parser": "~1.0.0",
    "debug": "~0.7.4",
    "jade": "~1.3.0"
  }
}

Comment: All files generated by ide and run locally so i suspect it may be a heroku related problem

Comment: Could this in any way be port related. app helgows runs in Webstorm that uses port 3000.app helgo runs with foreman on localhost:5000. App helgo runs fine on heroku.

Comment: Try `express.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000))` - ie. tell your app to bind to the PORT that Heroku provides you.

Comment: My question perhaps should have been How do I git push to heroku the node app generated by Webstorm ide when selecting a new node application type. Although Webstorm will show the app locally on port 5000 when binding the port as you suggest Heroku deployment fails. According to WS support "WebStorm provides no means for working with heroku". Which means you can open the project in the editor and then use the terminal and normal command lines to do any work.

Comment: WS simply uses the express-generator so I dont see why this doesn't deploy.